# Typescript/React infer exact component props from components record

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have simple form builder from config (React + Typescript) and I've stuck with infering exact component props from components record.
Online demo with TS error here: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-sky-o2bx5?file=/src/FormItem.tsx

Config looks like this:

```
const config: TFormItem[] = [
  {
    type: EFormType.Text,
    key: "form-item-1",
    label: "Form Item 1"
  },
  {
    type: EFormType.Select,
    key: "form-item-2",
    label: "Form Item 2",
    options: [
      { label: "Option 1", value: "option1" },
      { label: "Option 2", value: "option2" }
    ]
  }
];
```

type `TFormItem` is a union of each possible item config

In the end I have a component, that renders exact form component based on `type` field:

```
const formItemsMap: TFormItemMap = {
  [EFormType.Text]: FormItemText,
  [EFormType.Select]: FormItemSelect
};

const FormItem: FC<TFormItemProps<TFormItem>> = (props) => {
  const type = props.type as EFormType;
  const FormItemComponent = formItemsMap[type];
  const componentProps = props as ComponentProps<typeof FormItemComponent>;

  return <FormItemComponent {...componentProps} />;
};
```

It looks kinda fine - I can see that FormItemComponent has type like `FC<TFormItemText> | FC<TFormItemSelect>` and component props has type `(%all props for text component%) | (%all props for select component%)`.

But `FormItemComponent` gives me a type error `%my type% is not assignable to type 'never'`. I have tried different ways to infer exact component props (with type-guards and matching types for component and props with generic - I left some examples in the demo commented), but I still couldn't make it work fine with Typescript.

Answer (score 1):

I think it resolves to the `never` type because it can't decide at compile time whether it should be `FormItemText` or `FormItemSelect`.

But the actual selection should take place at run time anyway, and it can be done with a bit of imperative code by using the simple `switch` instead of a "map":

```
const FormItem: FC<TFormItemProps<TFormItem>> = (props) => {
  const type = props.type as EFormType;
  
  switch (type) {
    case EFormType.Text:
      return <FormItemText {...props as ComponentProps<typeof FormItemText>} />
    case EFormType.Select:
      return <FormItemSelect {...props as ComponentProps<typeof FormItemSelect>} />
  }
};
```

Here's a [forked sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-darkness-mqrm8?file=/src/FormItem.tsx) that shows it working.

Comment: Thanks! That was my first implementation of it, but i don't like how it's looking. I really want to do it record way

Comment: Trust your instincts and try to write clear code instead of clever code. It's easy to get over one's head in TypeScript typings.

Comment: Well, switch-case is surely working , but it wont’be scalable fine, so i guess it is not a great solution for me. Record thing has kinda simple logic and looks a lot better, but i just stuck with TS. I still think it’s a better solution even with ts-ignore